# Find first ReGex pattern following a different pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

**Objective:** find a second pattern and consider it a match only if it is the first time the pattern was seen following a different pattern.

**Background:**

I am using Python-2.7 Regex

I have a specific Regex match that I am having trouble with. I am trying to get the text between the square brackets in the following sample.

```
  Sample comments:

    [98 g/m2 Ctrl (No IP) 95 min 340oC         ]

    [    ]
```

I need the line:

```
98 g/m2 Ctrl (No IP) 95 min 340oC
```

The problem is the undetermined number of white-spaces, tabs, and new-lines between the search pattern `Sample comments:` and the match I want is giving me trouble.

**Best Attempt:**

I am able to match the first part easily,

```
match = re.findall(r'Sample comments:[.+\n+]+', string)
```

But I can't get the match to the length I want to grab the portion between the square brackets,

```
match = re.findall(r'Sample comments:[.+\n+]+\[(.+)\]', string)
```

**My Thinking:**

Is there a way to use ReGex to find the first instance of the pattern `\[(.+)\]` after a match of the pattern `Sample comments:`? Or is there a more robust way to find the bit between the square braces in my example case.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Not quite clear. Maybe [`Sample comments:\s*\[(.*?)\s*]`](https://regex101.com/r/rH4kS1/1) will suffice? See http://ideone.com/FZ5Ee0

Comment: Yours works, but I don't understand how. Does `\s` include white-space AND `\n`? There is definitely a newline in my sample, but it seems to work anyway.

Comment: Yes, `\s` matches any whitespace, vertical and horizontal ones.

Comment: Man do I feel stupid...thank you. That includes tab-space?

Comment: Googled it, yes it does.

Comment: [White space in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is the set: `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` , so yes tab is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using

```
r'Sample comments:\s*\[(.*?)\s*]'
```

See the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/rH4kS1/1) and [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/FZ5Ee0)

The point is the `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace, both  vertical (linebreaks) and horizontal. See [Python `re` reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `\s` 
>   When the `UNICODE` flag is not specified, it matches any whitespace character, this is equivalent to the set `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`. The `LOCALE` flag has no extra effect on matching of the space. If `UNICODE` is set, this will match the characters `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` plus whatever is classified as space in the Unicode character properties database.

**Pattern details**:

- `Sample comments:` - a sequence of literal chars
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (returned by `re.findall`) capturing 0+ any chars but a newline as few as possible up to the first...
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces and
- `]` - a literal `]` (note it does not have to be escaped outside the character class).

Comment: When I learned ReGex, I was ambiguously told that `\s` matches whitespace. I erroneously assumed this mean a space character. As a result, I didn't even think that part of the code was my problem. Thank you!

Comment: A space can be matched with a mere `[ ]` or a just space. If you want to match horizontal whitespace in Python, you actually can just use `[ \t]` or `[^\S\r\n]` (these patterns will do in most situations).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but `re.findall('Sample comments:[^\\[]*\\[([^\\]]*)\\]', string)` seems to work.

Or maybe `re.findall('Sample comments:[^\\[]*\\[[ \t]*([^\\]]*?)[ \t]*\\]', string)` if you want to strip the final spaces from your line?